# Change FaceColor and EdgeColor of Matplotlib Streamplot Arrows

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have some data in grid and I plot the streamlines with streamplot with color and width related to the speed. How can I change the color of the arrows, or just the edgecolors?
My goal is to emphasis the stream direction. If someone have another way to do it..

I tried to do it using `c.arrows`, editing `c.arrows.set_edgecolor`,`c.arrows.set_edgecolors`,`c.arrows.set_facecolor` and `c.arrows.set_facecolors` and nothing happened, even when I run `plt.draw()`

Figure:
[image: The Result of the code]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-10,-1, 50)
y = np.linspace(-30, -28, 50)

xi, yi = np.meshgrid(x,y)

u =  3*np.cos(xi)*((-3)*np.sin(yi))**3
v = 2*np.sin(xi)*3*np.cos(yi)
speed = np.sqrt((u**2)+(v**2))

lw = 4*speed/speed.max()

plt.ion()
plt.figure()
plt.plot(xi,yi,'-k',alpha=0.1)
plt.plot(xi.T,yi.T,'-k',alpha=0.1)
c = plt.streamplot(xi,yi,u,v,linewidth=lw,color=speed)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Beware, the analysis below may not be completely correct, I only took a cursory look into the source.)

It seems that `streamplot` does two things when it creates the arrows:

- adds arrow patches (type `FancyArrowPatch`) to the axes
- adds the same arrow patches to the `PatchCollection` (`c.arrows`)

For some reason (I guess getting the correct scaling is behind this) the collection does not seem to be used and is not added to the axes. So, if you change the color map or color of the collection, it has no effect on the drawing.

There might be more beautiful ways of doing this, but if you want, e.g., black arrows into your plot, you may do this:

```
import matplotlib.patches

# get the axes (note that you should actually capture this when creating the subplot)
ax = plt.gca()

# iterate through the children of ax
for art in ax.get_children():
    # we are only interested in FancyArrowPatches
    if not isinstance(art, matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch):
        continue
    # remove the edge, fill with black
    art.set_edgecolor([0, 0, 0, 0])
    art.set_facecolor([0, 0, 0, 1])
    # make it bigger
    art.set_mutation_scale(30)
    # move the arrow head to the front
    art.set_zorder(10)
```

This creates:

[image]

And then the usual warnings: This is ugly and fragile.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have a question. What if I want to keep the size?

Comment: Then do not touch the mutation scale, and set the edgecolor to be the same as the facecolor.

Comment: I tried don't change mutation scale, but the arrows be all small.

Comment: Do not set the edgecolor to zero/transparent. The arrow size seems to depend on the line width around the arrow head.

Comment: Hot tamale, but this is ugly and fragile! It's bizarrely non-orthogonal that Matplotlib provides a trivial means of modifying streamlines (e.g., the `lines` attribute of the object returned by `plt.streamplot()`) but _not_ streamline arrow heads.