# Cannot remove streamplot arrow heads from Matplotlib axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I remove a [streamplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot.html) from a Matplotlib plot without clearing everything (*i.e.* not using `plt.cla()` or `plt.clf()`)?

---

[`plt.streamplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot.html) returns a `StreamplotSet` (`streams` in the following example), which contains the stream lines (`.lines`) and arrow heads (`.arrows`).

Calling `streams.lines.remove()` removes the streamlines as expected.

However, I couldn’t find a way to remove the arrow heads: `stream.arrows.remove()` raises a `NotImplementedError`, and `stream.arrows.set_visible(False)` has no effect.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate streamplot data
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 10)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 10)
u, v = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Create streamplot
streams = plt.streamplot(x, y, u, v)

# Remove streamplot
streams.lines.remove()  # Removes the stream lines
streams.arrows.set_visible(False)  # Does nothing
streams.arrows.remove()  # Raises NotImplementedError
```

The following figure illustrates the example. 
Left: streamplot, right: remaining arrow heads.

[image: Streamplot example: full plot (left), and lines removed (right)]

---

For context, I’m trying to add streamlines to an existing imshow animation (built with [`matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html)). 
In this setup, only the image data are updated at each frame, and I can’t clear and redraw the full plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution seems to work and is inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25353915/4932316) answer. There are two ways:

1. Remove the arrow patch
2. Set the `alpha` parameter to 0

---

```
streams = plt.streamplot(x, y, u, v)

ax = plt.gca()

for art in ax.get_children():
    if not isinstance(art, matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch):
        continue
    art.remove()        # Method 1
    # art.set_alpha(0)  # Method 2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works! I wish there was a way to specifically target the streamplot arrows instead of all arrows, but as explained in the answer you link to, that’s probably not possible.